# Add new class to an element using XML::LibXML

Tags: perl, xml-libxml

I have a simple HTML snippet as follows:

`<div class="out"><p class="a">This is a paragraph. <p class="b">another</p></p></div>`

I need to add a new class `b` to the outer `p` element, resulting in the following expected result:

`<div class="out"><p class="a b">This is a paragraph. <p class="b">another</p></p></div>`

The inner `p` element should remain the same.

Is this possible?

Comment: (1) Does ""_outer `p` element_" mean the one right below `div` (2) Does "_add a new class_" means to add if `class` attribute exists, to whatever it has.  Or ...?

Comment: (1)Yes. (2)Add `class` attribute if it does not already exist; otherwise append the new class `b` to the existing `class` attribute.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Find the right *element* and change its attribute using [setAttribute](https://metacpan.org/pod/XML::LibXML::Element#setAttribute) method.

The code below uses requirements clarified in a comment: the paragraph of interest is the first one below a `div`, and its attribute `class` need be appended if it exists, or created.

```
use warnings;
use strict;
use feature 'say';

use XML::LibXML;

my $xml = q(<div class="out"><p class="a">This is a paragraph. )
        . q(<p class="b">another</p></p></div>);  #/

my $doc = XML::LibXML->load_xml(string => $xml);

my @nodes = $doc->findnodes('//p');

for my $node (@nodes) { 
    if ($node->parentNode->nodeName eq 'div') {
        my $attr_val = $node->getAttribute('class');
        $node->setAttribute(
            class => ($attr_val ? "$attr_val " : '') . 'b'
        );
    }   
}

say $doc;
```

This still assumes that the `p` doesn't have sibling paragraphs (so directly under the same `div`), or if it does that they should be changed in the same way as well.  If that's not the case then one should identify all those siblings and skip them.

The search is first for `p` and then the node is checked for its parent, in case some subtle refinements creep in ("*Yes, a `p` under a `div`, but except for the edge case of ...*").  But if that's not a concern and it is strictly the  `p` under a `div` then better go for that directly

```
my @nodes = $doc->findnodes('//div/p');
```

Then append to the `class` attribute or create it the same way as above.

The above prints

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<div class="out"><p class="a b">This is a paragraph. <p class="b">another</p></p></div>
```